# Sending a JavaScript Array to ActionScript not working in Safari for Windows

Tags: javascript, actionscript, safari

I am sending over a JavaScript Array to ActionScript. The JavaScript code is as follows:

```
var theSWF = window.document.getElementById('swfID');
var someID = '42';
var somethingElse = '23';
theSWF.someMethodExpectingArray([someID, somethingElse]);
```

The ActionScript code is as follows:

> ExternalInterface.addCallback("someMethodExpectingArray",
>   myClass.arrayMethod);
>
> public function arrayMethod( arrayInput:Array ) 
>   { 
>   // Do stuff with the array 
>   }

When I run this on Safari for Windows, arrayInput is null. However, this method works fine in Safari for Mac, IE, FF, Chrome, and the variable holds the actual array.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you send the data to AS3 as a string (JSON)?

Comment: Yes, that approach works, but I didn't want to have to it that way, unless I had to, and thought that it *should* work with Arrays as well.